# Finding voltages and currents on diodes

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, diodes

What are the voltages and currents on diodes D1 and D2 in the circuit below?

The diodes are modeled as ideal and allow current to pass at 0.7V.

R1=9k‎Ω, R2=1k‎Ω, R3=9.3k‎Ω

Edit: Sorry for making it seem like i just want you to do my homework, i have tried solving it but with no success, which is the reason why i'm asking this here. Anyways, I am assuming both diodes are conducting, but the setup of the circuit is confusing me and i can't seem to reach a solution

[image]

Comment: We will help with your homework to clarify your misconceptions, but we don't do your homework.  Edit your question showing what you can do.

Comment: This type of questions is solved by first making an *assumption*. The assumption is about the state of the diodes, like assume that both are conducting. then solve it. If no contradiction is found, the assumption is correct and you have the solution. If there is a contradiction - make another assumption and repeat.

Comment: wondering why they made R3 such an odd number

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Add the resistance directly to the schematic.  Making people go back and forth between the schematic and the text is obnoxious.

Comment: R1 and R2 are a voltage divider.  Start there.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Not really if D1 is conducting...

Comment: @EugeneSh. StainlessSteelRat is still right. Thevenin equivalent is a friend and applies to dividers perfectly well, regardless. Replace with \$V_{TH}\$ and \$R_{TH}\$ and examine again.

Comment: The trick is to start with what you know then work back. e.g. you know D2 must be conducting, so you know that voltage. What about D1? Is it conducting?

Comment: @jonk Yes, it *is* a voltage divider, but clearly not the same that will be formed by R1 and R2 alone.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Just pointing out that it's fine to suggest the voltage divider as a simplifying approach. And yes, it's the same  as formed by them alone.

Comment: Alright, now i'm thinking D1 isn't conducting because the voltage will be the same on resistors R1 and R3, which means there isn't a potential difference between the anode and cathode of the diode, making it easy to apply kirchoffs voltage law and then solve. Is this correct ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes and no..  You need to do that equation, with D1 removed, to figure out if D1 will be on or not.

Comment: @truenotwrong What does the voltage need to be on the left of D1 for it to be on? What is the voltage at the end of D1 due to the divider R1,R2?

Comment: @Trevor It needs to be at least 0.7V higher than on it's end, right? But due to the divider the voltage is the same on both sides, this is the only conclusion i'm coming to.

Comment: @truenotwrong, no... you know the top of D2 is at 0.7V. so left end of D1 needs to be 1.4V for it to be on... What's the voltage at the left end if D1 due to JUST R1 and R2...

Comment: Upvote.. really? Shows a research effort?

Comment: @Trevor it's 0.7V, since D2 is on the remaining voltage is 11.3V, the divider should split it equally meaning 5.65V before each resistor, also knowing D2 is on the voltage drop on the resistors must be 4.95V. If this isn't the case i'm having some huge misconceptions

Comment: @truenotwrong... nope... see my answer.

Comment: ROFL.  All I wanted was to get him started.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to do diodes is to remove them and calculate the voltages as shown on the left.

Now put the diodes back.

D2 will be conducting because the voltage at the top on the left is higher than the 0.7V required to turn it on. Note new voltages on right drawing.

Now you only have .5V across D1, so .... Is it on or off?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffdLFD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It is obviously off, but how did you calculate the voltage on R1?

Comment: @truenotwrong really? Simple voltage divider \$12v * R1/(R1+R2)\$

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for enduring my stupid and trivial questions, as you can see i am a complete beginner regarding circuit-analysis. Going to practice some more now that things are a lot clearer.

Comment: @truenotwrong no sweat, we all had to learn and some of it, like this one, isn't so obvious at first look.

Comment: @truenotwrong There's no need to be self-degrading. You are trying to understand things. All of us, even if we can't recall it anymore, have been there and struggled to apply the modest tools we had at the time. This site *can* provide the kind of interaction you cannot get from a book. So if you can handle the slings and arrows, from time to time, you may find the bits you require as you move forward. Don't let anyone stop you.

Comment: @Trevor Hmm. I also forgot. I wrote my answer almost more for some of the commentary going on than I did for the OP. Again, I'm glad you added another take.

Comment: @truenotwrong word of advice for here though. If you want answers try to show what you have tried, not just the question at hand. Folks get peeved if they think you just want them to do it for you. Even a snapshot of your scratchpad math goes a long way to show you are trying. Folks here are pleased to help others learn, but just doing it for them is NOT accepted as helping in any way.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot to both of you for helping a beginner understand. This site is really amazing, i wouldn't have gotten such quick and informative responses anywhere else on the internet. Also, analyzing circuits is surprisingly fun to do once you actually understand the things going on. I understand i made it seem that way, will take note for future posts.

Comment: @truenotwrong It will be easier to get answers if you put down your attempt in the question.  Homework without an attempt is locked.

Answer (score 1):

From reading all the comments, I've decided I need to clearly point out that Thevenin applies in helping to simplify the questions involved:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3qEol.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above schematic on the right is an ***exact*** equivalent of the one on the left. There is ***no*** behavioral difference between the two. None at all.

Now. Knowing your details about ideal diodes, is it possible for both \$D_1\$ and \$D_2\$ to be simultaneously ***ON***?

---

Reading over your comments above and below, and especially this one:

> it's 0.7V, since D2 is on the remaining voltage is 11.3V, the divider
>   should split it equally meaning 5.65V before each resistor, also
>   knowing D2 is on the voltage drop on the resistors must be 4.95V. If
>   this isn't the case i'm having some huge misconceptions

has suggested I need to add a few details to what I wrote. Sorry I didn't realize before. I gave you an equivalent schematic, thinking that would be enough. But I can see it's not.

Let's try another go at it, inspired by your comment about the divider splitting things evenly after subtracting a diode voltage. Here's the schematic again, but now assuming both diodes are ***ON*** and showing the various currents and node (a node is a shared wiring point on the schematic) voltages:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLJvQd.png)</sup>

One of the first things you should realize is that saying the word, ***divider***, doesn't mean that it ***equally*** divides things up. How it actually divides is a matter of the actual resistor values. You will notice that the value for \$R_1\$ is ***not*** the same as the value for \$R_2\$, for example. So these two resistors wouldn't equally divide anything up. They are unequal, so the division is also unequal.

The next thing to do, now, is to calculate all those currents on the assumption that both diodes are ***ON***. I am assuming you at least know about Ohm's law! Let's start with \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$:

$$\begin{align*}
I_1&=\frac{12\:\textrm{V}-1.4\:\textrm{V}}{R_1}\\\\&\approx 1.18 \:\textrm{mA}\\\\\\
I_2&=\frac{1.4\:\textrm{V}}{R_2}\\\\&=1.4 \:\textrm{mA}
\end{align*}$$

Already you should see a problem. Clearly, looking at the schematic, it must be the case that \$I_1=I_2+I_5\$. Or, put another way, if diode \$D_1\$ is ***ON*** then \$I_1\ge I_2\$. But from the above calculations, that statement is false.

By the sheer application of nothing more than logic, you have started with the assumption that \$D_1\$ is ***ON***, performed some calculations, and demonstrated that the necessary conclusions are then ***false***. Therefore, the assumption must be itself ***false***.

Comment: +1 Good answer... a couple of floors over the OP's head though me thinks... ;)

Comment: @Trevor Hmm. I can see the comments for your answer now. I concur. I guess I can't imagine a situation where this kind of question would have arisen without Thevenin being taught earlier. So it's a good idea that you added your answer! Good catch.

Comment: You really should know better than to give the answer to a homework problem.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I think this is more about others than the OP. We each may disagree at times about that. Which is as it should be. I spent years as a professor at the largest university here in my state. So I'm coming from that perspective, perhaps. Not likely to change over time, now. Old dog and all that.

Comment: Then maybe just wait a day or two before giving the answer.  As a professor, you probably didn't like your lazy students getting answers to homework given them.  I know you included a good explanation, but when the answer is there, lazy students will just skip over that part.

Comment: @OlinLathrop A long time ago I decided that focusing on lazy students is a waste of time and anguish. I look instead towards those who can benefit and don't even think about the rest. Too much wasted emotion beating against brick walls. Separately, here, I don't have the time (or memory) to go back days later. I do a few things and then just move on and rarely look back, putting out of my mind today what happened yesterday. So it's not in my playbook to revisit days later and add, then. I wish it could be, I suppose. But it's not. I'm interrupt driven, so to speak.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I agree with you, and had the OP not ventured into discussion and confusion in his comments, I would not have answered this question directly either. As I mentioned in a comment in my own answer, I don't believe over-helping is helping at all.. Some-where in there, is a fine line between teaching and answering though.